# usage of Plugin Description generator?

Tags: adtf, adtf3

I need help in one problem i.e my plugin description is not being generated . My .adtfplugin is generated properly. And i wanted to generated plugin description using adtf_plugin_description_generator.exe.
It requires some opencv dlls and one specific system file.

So i went to my adtf bin path and ran

```
adtf_plugin_description_generator.exe -plugin=C:/Users/XXX/myplugin.adtfplugin -system=C:/Users/XXX/xxx.adtfsystem -dynamiclinks=[C:/Users/XXX/opencv.dll;C:/Users/XXX/someotherdlls]
```

When i ran above command in cmd shell , i get error like

```
2021-04-06 16:03:45 [ERROR]: Could not register plugin in runtime Result code '-20 '(ERR_NOT_FOUND) - Could not load plugin "C:\Filters\example": file or dependencies not found [File: C:\jenkins\ws\A3_bld\PLATFORM\WIN7_x64_vc140\source\src\libraries\ucom3\src\runtime.cpp] [Line: 1759] [Func: adtf::ucom::ant::detail::cRuntime::cRuntimePrivate::LoadPluginImpl] [main.cpp(229)]                                

2021-04-06 16:03:45 [ERROR]: Result code '-20 '(ERR_NOT_FOUND) - Could not load plugin "C:\Filters\example": file or dependencies not found [File: C:\jenkins\ws\A3_bld\PLATFORM\WIN7_x64_vc140\source\src\libraries\ucom3\src\runtime.cpp] [Line: 1759] [Func: adtf::ucom::ant::detail::cRuntime::cRuntimePrivate::LoadPluginImpl] [main.cpp(693)]
```

Please excuse me if the question is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at https://support.digitalwerk.net/adtf/v3/guides/sdk_generate_plugin_description.html (in detail) and https://support.digitalwerk.net/adtf/v3/guides/tools_adtf_plugin_description_generator.html (CMake Support), because you do not really make use of the ADTF Plugin Description Generator itself, even when you require additonal libraries, CMake is the best choice as post build step.

Keep in mind that this is the documentation of the latest ADTF (>= 3.11) and there might be some functionality your version does not provide yet (your call -plugin might point that you are running an old version because it has been changed to --plugin for example). Its recommended to migrate to latest ADTF especially regarding bugfixing and extended functionality.

Anyway, if this documentation won't point you to the solution, have a look at all the given tutorials and examples within the guides which will do this every time. Please also point out the entire log messages at which point the loading breaks and especially if the file exists (also the dependencies). Your log snippet tries to load a folder (C:\Filters\example but this should be somethin like path/to/some_filter.adtfplugin), which is maybe an error within the system file, so check the paths and content.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Normally i have used cmake to generate plugin description everytime. This time since it is getting some error, i have tried also to use plugin_description_generator separately, so i thought this might give some more information. As you said there might be some problem with system file, because plugin is there in correct path and also dependencies are there in correct path. I will give a look into the system file. Also i am using adtf of version 3.3 , need to upgrade that. Is there any way where we can generate .adtfsystem file automatically?